# How to open the track panel in GameMaker

Tags: drag-and-drop, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I am new to Game Maker. I opened a sequence and accidentally closed the track panel. I don't know how to open it, and I need the track panel for my game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Press arrows to open Track Panel and Timeline in Sequence Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m63wO.png)

[Or press Reset Layout in Layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip4UM.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! I tried the arrows, but the "Reset Layout" worked for me.